# accessing a conditional iterate in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterable

I am parsing a large number of of huge XML files (up to 1GB) and I am cross-referencing a list of about 700 possible matches for a given field. If I find a match I would like to know which match I hit from my list rather than using the text from the field itself.

I have the following line in my code

`<-- outside loops iterating over outer layer tags tags -->
     if any(re.search(s, parsedOutTag.text) for s in preCompiledRegexList):
         <-- checking innner layer tags for additional content-->`

I am wondering how to access the iterant `s` directly when the condition is satisfied. I currently have a very hack'ish implementation of what I need to happen.

I have to admit, and I am sure it is obvious, I adopted this line for the efficiency from another question here on Stack Overflow so I don't really know all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `any` function shortcircuits, I believe, so even if you could access the `s` binding from the generator expression, it would only ever be the first matching instance. If that's what you want, then you can just unwrap the `if` condition:

```
for s in preCompiledRegexList:
    if re.search(s, parsedOutTag.text):
        # checking inner layer tags for additional content
        break
```

If you want to process all items in `preCompiledRegexList` that match, either remove the `break` above, or use a generator that only yields values that match the required condition:

```
for outer_s in (inner_s for inner_s in preCompiledRegexList of re.search(s, parsedOutTag.text):
    # checking inner layer tags for additional content
```

(Note that having different `outer_s` and `inner_s` labels isn't necessary, I just wanted to highlight that they exist in separate scopes.)

Comment: I don't lose any computational efficiency by dropping the `for` loop outside of the `if any()` statement?

Comment: I don't believe you will, no. If you're processing _all_ matching items, it might seem to take longer than the `any` call, but as mentioned, that's because `any` will stop processing values on the first one that is `True`.

Comment: No, I'm not processing all items from the Regex List. I'm only expecting one match from the list if any, more often than not I expect no match.